# Amazon RDS db.r4.16xlarge not much faster than m3.medium

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, performance-testing, amazon-rds

I have a postgres database with ~37K rows with some indexed columns and one jsonb column.
Using m3 instance type and querying a certain query which involves json ops it takes 93 seconds, the same query on db.r4.16xlarge takes 83 seconds, repeatedly. Shouldn't this difference be much more significant?
Assuming, with 488GB of Ram, everything can be served from memory.. is the RDS not configured to be optimized that way and use the memory available?

Example query:

This is another query with same 'issue':

```
explain analyze
SELECT 
       u.id::text as id, 
       u.date_created, 
       u.email, 
       AVG((s.fields->'someFunctionPerTrip'->>'value')::numeric) as risk,
       ROUND(SUM((s.fields ->> 'totalDistanceCumulative')::real)) as distance,
       COUNT(s.id) as trips,
       ROUND(SUM((s.fields ->> 'totalTimeSec')::real)/3600) as duration,
       (MAX(s.start_timestamp) - MIN(s.start_timestamp))/(1000*3600*24),
       ROUND(AVG((s.fields ->> 'avgFuelConsumption')::numeric/2),3) as avg_fuel_consumption
FROM  user u, trip s
WHERE s.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Result:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=5291.70..5308.76 rows=273 width=274) (actual time=20594.922..20595.460 rows=273 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: u.id"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=81.14..3209.34 rows=37861 width=128) (actual time=0.311..72.824 rows=37861 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (s.user_id = u.id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on trip s  (cost=0.00..2607.61 rows=37861 width=54) (actual time=0.005..19.026 rows=37861 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=77.73..77.73 rows=273 width=82) (actual time=0.297..0.297 rows=273 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 39kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on user u  (cost=0.00..77.73 rows=273 width=82) (actual time=0.002..0.186 rows=273 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.619 ms"
"Execution time: 20595.608 ms"
```

There is an index on every id column. Thanks for helping me understanding it!

Taking out ALL json ops makes it run in 80ms. Taking out the nested op `s.fields->'someFunctionPerTrip'->>'value'` makes it run in 10 seconds.

So which RDS is best for parsing nested json? The data structure is provided and I cannot change it.

Comment: You are CPU bound. Are the columns json or jsonb? If json try jsonb as it is preparsed and values are stored as actual binary values instead of as text.

Comment: its jsonb. I will try with a real server vs rds now

Answer (score -1):

Chances are that 37K rows will fit in memory in both instance types. This suggests that the bottleneck is not storage.

Is it possible that it's just the JSON operations that take a long time?

[performance_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html) might help you dig deeper into where the actual time is spent.

Answer (score -1):

The instance type you have chosen is very powerful and would perform well for potentially hundreds (thousands?) of transactions per second. However, running a single query is not a suitable way to measure the throughput of a database.

When testing database performance, you should simulate the query load that will be typical of your application.

If your use-case is purely on a small set of data and SELECT performance is very important, you could consider using an in-memory database. That will be faster than any traditional relational database.

Comment: I agree. Given that I operate on a database which is postgresql and exists with populated data in RDS how can I get the maximum SELECT performance ? How can I make it read all into memory ?

Comment: The `Seq Scan on trip s` suggests that `trip.user_id` is not indexed. Aside from that, it is likely the JSON parsing that is causing the query to slow down. As a test, try removing every SELECT entry that uses `->>` and check the performance. If it runs faster, then I would suggest converting the JSON data into actual fields in the database table so that queries can be optimized directly against the fields, without parsing JSON.

Comment: There is an index

`CREATE INDEX trip_user_id_idx
  ON public.trip
  USING btree
  (user_id);`

I agree the json parsing might be the problem, but how can I get the fastest json parsin on RDS. The data is given.

Comment: I suggest you test it first to confirm that the JSON parsing is causing the slow-down.

Comment: I can confirm, taking out ALL json ops makes it run in 80ms. See updated question

Comment: The best method is NOT to parse the JSON in your queries. Preferably, expand the JSON into actual database fields when the data is loaded. Then, just perform normal queries on the fields. You could convert the existing data by adding columns to the existing table, then performing an UPDATE to extract the JSON data and save it into the columns. This allows the database to operate at its full potential.